# dynamically selecting specified column from a specified row by 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, sql

I am relatively new to PHP and MySQL.

I have a table which is like this...

```
id      name       username      app      sdate    edate   
===    =======     ========    ===      =====    ======  
 1      tanvir      tanvir      1       2012     2012       
 2      Ranvir      Ranvir      1       2011     2013      
 3      john        john        2       2011     2012     
 4      Rakib       Rakib       1       2011     2012
```

Now I want to fetch more than one row at a time and put them into a 2 dimensional array variable dynamically such that I can make a condition...

```
if(array[variable containing all the value of sdate of each row] == '' 
  &&  
array[variable containing all the value of username of each row] == '') 
{
  \*then some code *\
}
```

Here the `sdate` should not be `sdate`  and `username` should not be `username`. Instead of `sdate` and `username` there should be the variable more like 2 dimensional variable that will indicate the a particular row and a particular column... make it clear again by giving an example... If I **dynamically** wanted to select the number 3 row's `sdate` and `username` and put it to `if` condition(mentioned) earlier, then how can I do it... I mentioned dynamically because every row's `sdate` and `username` should be checked as like as the `if` condition. Is it possible?

If possible, than what's the way?

Comment: It's unlikely you actually need the added complexity of a 2d array

Comment: I think your question is unclear and I can't make heads or tails of what you want.

Comment: You want to make an array of database records in PHP? Or what do you want to do?